# Are barplots appropriate for showing means?

Tags: data-visualization, mean

My data are differences of two values. I try to show the data with points (two per "x-axis-value") and their mean as bars. See here: 
[image: means as barplots]

I feel that bars could be misleading insofar as they imply a continuous range of values and not just the mean. On the other hand, bars are much more noticeable for comparative purposes.

Secondly, here is a plot with means shown as horizontal "lines". They are likely more appropriate for showing a mean but I find it hard to compare the means and place the indivdual points with respect to the means by eye.

Here is the second plot:

[image: means as "lines"]

If I would use the first plot in a thesis, do you think this will be found faulty, so to say?

Comment: Do you have just 2 points in each case? If so, the mean is not adding much information. You could consider omitting it entirely.

Comment: The vertical lines connecting the points (for each X-axis value) are also a bit redundant, especially the bit connecting them to the X-axis when both values are >0

Comment: In addition to mkt's point, in some cases (green bar) the line extends to zero but probably there are not points there?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same. Redundancy of means and the lines connecting the points are also no good.:/ thank you i definitely need to consider that

Comment: Two points and optionally a short line showing the mean seem reasonable. I wouldn't extend the line to zero as seems to arise in two or three cases.  On a different level, we can't speak for people reading your thesis, just for ourselves.

Comment: @NickCox u think the mean is somewhat meaningful in this graph?

Comment: I don't know what these data are really, but imagine that whether the mean is positive or negative could be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a revision:

1.) The lines connecting the points are now substituted by a background color
(pairs of colors here are just options), (points are now bars)

2.) mean is left out

[image]